# Linear Algebra Matrices to equations

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-equations

> Show that
>   $$\operatorname{det}\;\begin{bmatrix}
> 1&1&1\\x^2&y^2&z^2\\x^4&y^4&z^4
> \end{bmatrix}=(y^2-x^2)(z^2-x^2)(z^2-y^2)$$

I am doing my homework,and this question came up.
I need to know about subject of this question so i can study and solve it.
I tried to look it up from textbook and couldn't find it.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange.  It looks like a [Vandermonde determinant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vandermonde_matrix)

Comment: just compute the determinant and try to factorize the expression you get

Comment: You can prove it by computing the determinant, but it’s better if you remember it as a standard proof.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are given a matrix with entries in some polynomial ring, say $\Bbb Z[x,y,z]$ or $\Bbb R[x,y,z]$ (in this specific case it does not really matter, what the underlying ring is). That being said, you can compute the determinant of a matrix just like any other matrix, for example (since we are given a $3\times 3$ matrix) via *Sarrus‘ rule*:
$$\operatorname{det}\;\begin{bmatrix}
1&1&1\\x^2&y^2&z^2\\x^4&y^4&z^4
\end{bmatrix}=y^2z^4 + z^2x^4 + x^2y^4 - x^4y^2 - y^4z^2 - z^4x^2$$
Now expanding the term of the desired result should give you this as well.

Comment: So Should i take determinant of this matrice,factorize it and leave it that way?
Do i need to add anything else?

Comment: Yes, I think this is exactly what you are asked to do. Note however that, since you know the desired result, it is much easier to expand this than factorizing the term resulting from computing the determinant...

Answer (score 0):

$\operatorname{det}\;\begin{bmatrix}
1&1&1\\x^2&y^2&z^2\\x^4&y^4&z^4
\end{bmatrix}
\\=\operatorname{det}\;\begin{bmatrix}
1&0&0\\x^2&y^2-x^2&z^2-x^2\\x^4&y^4-x^4&z^4-x^4
\end{bmatrix}\tag*{}$ (using the transformation $C_2\rightarrow C_2-C_1 $ and $C_3\rightarrow C_3-C_1$)
$\\=(y^2-x^2)(z^4-x^4)-(y^4-x^4)(z^2-x^2)
\\=(y^2-x^2)(z^2-x^2)((z^2+x^2)-(y^2+x^2))
\\=(y^2-x^2)(z^2-x^2)(z^2-y^2)\tag*{}$